# Twitch API json response

Tags: php, json, twitch

im trying to get data with `json_decode()` from twicth API however all the guides about json are having a main array which twitch doesn't provide.

This is a sample the code i'm using:

```
$api = file_get_contents("twitch.json");
$json = json_decode($api, true);
echo $json['channel'][0]['title'];
```

And here is the twitch response:
http://pastebin.com/18RgfVsZ (too large to paste it here)

Answer (score 2):

The JSON response here has a main array, with only one object in it.

Your example code works if you get that main Object (`$json[0]`) and then get properties from there. e.g.:

```
...
echo $json[0]['channel']['title'];
```

See prettified JSON summary below. Bracket indicates Array, first brace is main Object and indented brace is Channel object within the main Object:

```
A O            C
[
  {
    "subcategory": "shooters",
    ...
    "embed_enabled": false,
    "channel": {
      "subcategory": "shooters",
      ...
      "category_title": ""
    }
    "up_time": "Thu Feb 20 10:35:50 2014",
    ...
    "channel_view_count": 11107837
  }
]
```